# get first occurred only in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an arrayX of three elements , and i'm using $.inArray() to search for this three element in another arrayY ... and returning the location for each X element in Y

```
X = [1,2,3] ;
y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2] ;
```

But there is duplication in `y`, 1 occurred twice in `y[0]` and `y[3]`

The real example is here http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/kHG9K/

How do I get the first 1 occupancy and skip the others?

I'm pushing the location of 1,2,3 in an array with the first occurred of each one

Comment: probably you didn't save your fiddle. first save it and then give the updated link.

Comment: I think that's what `$.inArray` already doing (returning the index of the first occurrence...). What is the problem? *edit:* Your jsfiddle is totally different than the example you posted here. You should update the example here to reflect that you have a multidimensional array and search for one of the values of the inner arrays.

Comment: As felix said, this is exactly what $.inArray does.

Comment: if you don't understand the question it is your problem .... the question is clear

Comment: @Mina: Your fiddle and your example differ. Your fiddle needs a different approach than this example. If you are not willing to describe your case clearly, don't wonder that people are confused. Only based on the information provided in this post, the answer is : `$.inArray` already works like that and hence you don't have any problem. Be nice, you want something from us, not the other way round.

Comment: @Mina if it was clear, we wouldn't be asking for clarification. after all, this is _your_ problem, we are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kHG9K/18/

I just remove the item from the array once it has been found.

```
    if (start >= 0) {
        alert(y[i] + " " + "found it" + " " + " location" + z);
        y[i] = null;
    }
```

NOTE: That's not the right way to loop through an array. Use `for(index;index<length;index++)` to avoid quirks.

Comment: That seems to be totally different than what the OP originally wanted... this question is really confusing... wouldn't just terminating the loop after the element was found be more straightforward?

Comment: @FelixKling, I thought so too. Actually my first approach. But it fails due to the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @FelixKling, to be honest I didn't read his question at all. I simply edited the fiddle base off the title.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine without jQuery and `$.inArray`:

```
x = [1,2,3] ;
y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2] ;

var z = {};

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
        if (x[i] == y[j]) {
            z[x[i]] = j;
            break;
        }

console.log(z);
```

​`z` is an object containing elements from `x` as keys and its' positions as values.

**UPDATE.** Applying this to your example, here is the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kHG9K/19/

Comment: I assume the array he posted here is only simplified... in his fiddle he has a two-dimensional array, which changes things a bit.

Comment: Well, not really. One more loop assuming if next dimension size may vary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var firstOccurrences = [];
var y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2];

for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
    firstOccurrences.push(y.indexOf(x[i]));       
}

console.log(firstOccurrences);
```

---

Edit: as noted below, indexOf() isn't reliable in older versions of IE. Here's a more idiomatic jQuery approach:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2];

var firstOccurrences = $.map(x, function(item) { return $.inArray(item, y); });
```

Comment: why complicate matter when $.inArray does exactly the same thing as the questioner wants?

Comment: How does this complicate things? I just used a native Array method, vs. a jQuery method.

Comment: Well, jQuery abstracts from browser differences. `indexOf` won't work in all IE versions... you should at least mention that.

Comment: Good call. I actually had forgotten about the browser limitation.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHG9K/16/

```
var x = [1,2,3] ;
var y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2] ;

function firstOccurence()
{
    for ( var a in x )
    {
       return $.inArray( x[a] , y );
    }
}

alert( firstOccurence() );    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/kETAH/3/)

You have to use :

`$.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex] )`

In your case, to get the index of value 1 from y array, you can simply use:

`$.inArray('1', y)`

To check each value of x, if exists in y, and to save each index in an third array z:

```
var x = [1,2,3], y = [1,5,6,1,6,9,3,2], z = new Array(), i;
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var indexInY = $.inArray(x[i], y); // You get index -1 if the value is not found.
    z.push(indexInY);
    alert("Does x[" + i + "] with value = " + x[i] + 
                          " exist in y array? " + 
                          ((indexInY != -1) ? "Yes at position " + indexInY + "." : "No.")
                         );
}
alert("Indexes of x elements in y: [" + z + "]");

// Results:
// Does x[0] with value = 1 exist in y array? Yes at position 0.
// Does x[1] with value = 2 exist in y array? Yes at position 7.
// Does x[2] with value = 3 exist in y array? Yes at position 6.
//
// Indexes of x elements in y: [0,7,6]
```

Note that you will receive index **-1** if the value you are looking wasn't found in the array.
​

Fiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/kETAH/3/)